# How to search a file in the console of AWS-S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded an image to S3 on Amazon Web Services. I just wanted to search for the image in the admin console of S3. I cannot find any search options there. Is there any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979218/how-do-you-search-an-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: You mean by coding... I am just needed through the panel... is that not possible as said there?

Comment: If you do not wish to code anything, then why did you add PHP as one of the tabs?

Comment: I just want it both the ways, so that I can verify manually as a process of validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once in the [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/) (e.g. in the bucket folder), you can just start typing the name of the object you are looking for. The list will refresh with the top file being the one you're searching for.

[image: Example]

Comment: Arjan it isn't working as you said..1. after opening into the bucket 2. I just started to type the file name but couldn't able get such a label that you are getting...

Comment: Do I have to enable this type-search anywhere on the console panel?

Comment: No you don't have to enable it. It's called the jump feature (see [link](http://bit.ly/1l6ostY)). Try in different browsers.

Comment: I tried in safari. I am using windows7, chrome current version.

Comment: I got it. Where I missed was.. I was using keypad on keyboard. When I started to use number keys which also has special chars... it started to work. But we cannot get the exact file through this...it will just work for the prefix. Thanks. I think only the `ListBucket` can get the exact result that I wanted..