# How to search an Amazon S3 Bucket using Wildcards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filtering

[This stackoverflow answer helped a lot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979218/how-do-you-search-an-amazon-s3-bucket) However, I want to search for all PDFs inside a given bucket.

1. I click "None".
2. Start typing.
3. I type `*.pdf`
4. Press `Enter`

Nothing happens.  Is there a way to use wildcards or regular expressions to filter bucket search results via the online S3 GUI console?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As stated in a comment, Amazon's UI can only be used to search by prefix as per their own documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/searching-for-objects-by-prefix.html

There are other methods of searching but they require a bit of effort. Just to name two options, [AWS-CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#cli-aws-s3) application or [Boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html) for Python.

*I know this post is old but it is high on Google's list for s3 searching and does not have an accepted answer. The other answer by Harish is linking to a dead site.*

UPDATE 2020/03/03: AWS link above has been removed. This is a link to a very similar topic that was as close as I could find. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

Comment: Let it be noted that this documentation didn't exist at the time the question was asked.

Comment: Also let it be noted that this documentation no longer exists, and redirects to the documentation home.

Comment: Also let it be noted that *not* allowing richer searches and *only* sorting items on the current console page makes things impossible to find in the S3 console. (Definitely send AWS feedback from the console.)

Answer (score 35):

**AWS CLI search:**
In AWS Console,we can search objects within the directory only but not in entire directories, that too with prefix name of the file only(S3 Search limitation).

The best way is to use AWS CLI with below command in Linux OS

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name/ --recursive | grep search_word | cut -c 32-
```

**Searching files with wildcards**

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name/ --recursive |grep '*.pdf'
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will help me find all PDFs?

Comment: aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name/   --recursive |grep *.pdf

Comment: I had to use a period: '.*.pdf' - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069333/12383690

Comment: If you're going to search for multiple files/patterns and the bucket prefix has many objects, it can save a lot of time to redirect the output to a `.txt` file. This way you only download once and can `grep` repeatedly without network latency

Comment: There's a risk this will result in a lot AWS calls. If you have a million objects in your bucket it will take 1000 calls to complete as it pages in blocks of 1000. It's performing the filter client side where prefix searches happen server side.

Comment: @Momo extending what you said a bit more, the correct syntax for searching for file extensions would be `| grep '.*\.pdf$'`  The first period means "any character", the asterisk means 0-inf times, \ is to escape the next period so it literally looks for that (rather than any single character) and the $ at the end means that no characters after this point are accepted. A shorter version is to actually leave off the initial .* entirely (`| grep '\.pdf$'`) as grep matches the word anywhere on the line without the $ anchor

Answer (score 14):

You can use the copy function with the `--dryrun` flag:

```sh
aws s3 ls s3://your-bucket/any-prefix/ .\ --recursive --exclude * --include *.pdf --dryrun
```

It would show all of the files that are PDFs.

Comment: I get Unknown options: . --recursive

Comment: That's because @user2568374 had the right idea but the wrong example. It should be:  
```aws s3 cp s3://your-bucket/any-prefix/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.pdf" --dryrun```

Comment: Comparing the AWS docs, it seems `aws s3 cp` has a wildcard feature like Yossi has indicated here, `aws s3 ls` does not seem to have a wildcard feature.

Comment: What is the role of .\ or . here?

Comment: @Yossi works only with non-partial directories path

Answer (score 7):

If you use boto3 in Python it's quite easy to find the files. Replace 'bucket' with the name of the bucket.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    if '.pdf' in obj.key:
        print(obj.key)
```

Comment: It's frustrating that they can't do "Postfix" since they already have a Prefix variable.

Comment: suffix........?

Answer (score 4):

The CLI can do this; `aws s3` only supports prefixes, but `aws s3api` supports arbitrary filtering. For s3 links that look like `s3://company-bucket/category/obj-foo.pdf`, `s3://company-bucket/category/obj-bar.pdf`, `s3://company-bucket/category/baz.pdf`, you can run

```bash
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "company-bucket" --prefix "category/" --query "Contents[?ends-with(Key, '.pdf')]"
```

or for a more general wildcard

```bash
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "company-bucket" --prefix "category/" --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'foo')]"
```

or even

```bash
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "company-bucket" --prefix "category/obj" --query "Contents[?ends_with(Key, '.pdf') && contains(Key, 'ba')]"
```

The full query language is described at [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#grammar).

Comment: there is a small typo in the last example: It should be `ends_with` as per https://jmespath.org/specification.html#ends-with

Comment: I assume if you use s3api though it's still only doing a prefix query and then filtering it client side? All the s3 docs I can find only ever mention list handling prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation using the Java SDK suggests it can be done:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

Specifically the function `listObjectsV2Result` allows you to specify a prefix filter, e.g. "files/2020-01-02*" so you can only return results matching today's date.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Result.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess the files were uploaded from a unix system and your downloading to windows so s3cmd is unable to preserve file permissions which don't apply on NTFS.

To search for files and grab them try this from the target directory or change ./ to target:

```
for i in `s3cmd ls s3://bucket | grep "searchterm" | awk '{print $4}'`; do s3cmd sync --no-preserve $i ./; done
```

This works in WSL in windows.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this in one of my project but its a bit of hard coding

```
import subprocess
bucket = "Abcd"
command = "aws s3 ls s3://"+ bucket + "/sub_dir/ | grep '.csv'"
listofitems = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True,)
listofitems = listofitems.decode('utf-8')
print([item.split(" ")[-1] for item in listofitems.split("\n")[:-1]])
```