# How to find a file in Amazon S3 bucket without knowing the containing folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Amazon S3 bucket has a folder structure that looks like the below.

- bucket-name\00001\file1.txt
- bucket-name\00001\file2.jpg
- bucket-name\00002\file3.doc
- bucket-name\00001\file4.ppt

If I only know file name **file3.doc** and bucket name **bucket-name** how can i search for **file3.doc** in **bucket-name**. If I knew, it is in folder **00002**, I could simply go to the folder and start typing the file name but I have no way to know in which folder the file I am searching for is under.

Comment: Unfortunately I think your options are limited. Recursive loop will probably be your best best. S3 isn't supposed to be used in this manner

Comment: Do you wish to obtain it programmatically, or is a command-line sufficient? In what context are you looking for the file (eg is it a once-off request, regular job, part of a bigger app, etc)?

Answer (score 38):

You can easily do this with the AWS CLI.

```
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET-NAME/ --recursive | grep FILE-NAME.TXT
```

Comment: this should be the top answer as it correctly answers the question

Comment: Can we use the same command to find a folder instead of file? 

```aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET-NAME/ --recursive | grep FOLDER-NAME```

Answer (score 14):

Using only the AWS CLI, you can run a `list-objects` against the bucket with the `--query` parameter. This will not be a fast operation, as it runs locally after fetching the file list, rather than inside s3's api.

```
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'file3')]"

[
    {
        "LastModified": "2017-05-31T20:36:28.000Z",
        "ETag": "\"b861daa5cc3775f38519f5de6566cbe7\"",
        "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
        "Key": "00002/file3.doc",
        "Owner": {
            "DisplayName": "owner",
            "ID": "123"
        },
        "Size": 27032
    }
]
```

The benefit of using `--query` over just piping to grep is that you'll get the full response including all available metadata usually included in `list-objects`, without having to monkey around with before and after arguments for the grep.

See this post on [Finding Files in S3](https://lukewaite.ca/posts/2017/08/03/s3-find-files.html) for further information including a similar example which shows the benefit of having metadata, when files of the same name end up in different directories.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to use a command line tool like [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) if you don't know where it is at all:

```
s3cmd --recursive ls s3://mybucket | grep "file3"
```

but some limited search is possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21836343/562557

Comment: These days, it's normally recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has functionality for all AWS services (not just Amazon S3).