# AWS S3 API - search by meta data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use AWS s3 for storing few thousand files per hour and it works like a charm. I'm curious to see if I can filter them based on time or date or any meta data I have with these objects. I'm able to run a node process to get the objects list and play around for date and time but not meta data. Is there any other way do it or a better option ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979218/how-do-you-search-an-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: What AWS SDK are you using?

Comment: Its not a duplicate since I;m looking for some option using SDK. Not looking for a simple lookup by object name but to get some stats based on the objects.

Answer (score 13):

No, you cannot filter on metadata with the S3 API.

To do what you're asking, you would need to List Objects ([GET Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html)) on the bucket to get all the keys, then individually ask for metadata for each key ([HEAD Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html)). Then in your own code, you can filter out objects that don't match.

Obviously, this would be very slow to run live if you have more than a few thousand objects. You'll want to either filter down to a manageable number based on prefix or keep an index yourself (elastic search, maybe?). It's common to encode some metadata in the object keys so that you can filter by prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I can try adding prefix to objects then.

Comment: Has this answer changed since 2015? I'm looking into this right now.

Comment: I'm also looking into lifecycle rules based on metadata values and would like to know if this has changed.

Comment: In 2019, it may be worth looking at [s3select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) or [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) with [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/).

Comment: Any changes ? I am also looking at "You'll want to either filter down to a manageable number based on prefix or keep an index yourself (elastic search, maybe?)" preferably for a single bucket